# Prestashop problem with product combinations

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've added a few products with product combinations but when I select one in the frontend I get this error:

```
An error occurred while processing your request
```

In the logs I found this sql error

```
PrestaShopDatabaseException]
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') GROUP BY pac.id_product_attribute ' at line 8


    SELECT
      pac.`id_product_attribute`
    FROM
      `ps_product_attribute_combination` pac
    INNER JOIN `ps_product_attribute` pa ON pa.id_product_attribute = pac.id_product_attribute
    WHERE
      pa.id_product = 73
    AND pac.id_attribute IN ()
    GROUP BY
      pac.id_product_attribute
    HAVING
    COUNT(pa.id_product) = 0 LIMIT 1
```

I am using prestashop 1.7.6.0
Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Have you updated Prestashop from some older version?
What PHP and SQL versions you use?

Go to Advanced Parameters -> Performance, enable Debug mode and check the error page.
Show the screenshot of the full error, that will appear

Comment: No it's a fresh installation without upgrade. I've already enabled debug mode but it's only for backend. In the frontend I am getting this error and in the logs and dev toolbar I see the sql error.

Comment: What PHP and SQL versions do you use?